# Auto register a new user based on facebook login user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to connect my app to facebook using FOSOAuthBundle and FOSUserBundle. When connecting to facebook, it works fine and after connect to facebook, the app will be redirect to register form that created by FOSUserBundle in order to create a new user that have been connected to facebook. Now I want my app to create a new user automatically based on facebook user information such as username = facebook username, email = facebook email, etc after my app has successfully connected to facebook. How to do that?

Here is some of my code:

**User.php**

```
namespace Wirata\MainBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $facebookID;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setfacebookID($facebookID)
    {
        $this->facebookID = $facebookID;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    ...

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

        ...

    firewalls:

        ...

        secure_area:
            pattern: ^/

            oauth:
                failure_path: /connect
                login_path: /connect
                check_path: /connect
                provider: fos_userbundle
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge

            anonymous:    true
            logout:
                path:           /logout
                target:         /


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: secure_area
    user_class: Wirata\MainBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    false 


hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: secure_area
    connect:
        confirmation: true
        #account_connector: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
        #registration_form_handler: hwi_oauth.registration.form.handler.fosub_bridge
        #registration_form: fos_user.registration.form

    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           'xxxxxxx'
            client_secret:       'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            scope:               "email"
            infos_url:           'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=username,name,picture.type(square)'

    http_client:
        verify_peer: false    
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30

        properties:
            facebook: facebookID
```

Comment: You can't to get facebook user's email, as I know, but you can use one of nickname@facebook.com / fbid@facebook.com for notifications...

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write quite a bit of code in order to achieve what you are looking for. Check out this Gist which contains the solution to your problem and also a nice explanation:

https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

**EDIT**

In order to get the email from the user in those OAuth resource owners which support it, you will need to define the scope of the data you want to get. For example, for Facebook it would be:

```
hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            scope: "email"
```

You will need to see under the resource owner's documentation to see what kind of data you can request in your scope. For Facebook, see this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#categories

Comment: It's helping. Now I could create a new user automatically but still have the same problems. Following the instruction on that link, I only got the facebookID, still didn't get the username and email. the `$username` only save the facebookID value. how can I get the username and email value from facebook?

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out!

Comment: But I have added the `scope: "email"` in my resource_owners, and I still don't get the email.

Comment: Have you reconnected the account? You have to do so in order to refresh the permissions (delete the authorized application in the Facebook account you are trying to connect and then trying again).

Comment: Problem solved. I only add `email=$response->getEmail()` and `realname=$response->getRealName()` in my FOSUBUserProvider.php that I've created by following the instruction from the link that you gave before, and save it to my database. Thanks for the instruction.